# Botón se cambia de fila al insertar elementos en un HTML

Tags: javascript, html, select2, bootstrap

> Buenas, el problema está dado cuando cargo elementos a mi página. En las imágenes, luego del código, van a poder apreciar con exactitud lo que sucede.

**crear-menu.php** -> En el div `.nuevoIngrediente` se irán cargando los `select` para elegir ingredientes a medida que el usuario toque el botón **«Agregar Ingrediente»** (Vas cargando ingredientes para formar una receta, o en este caso un menu).

```php
<!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR EL CLIENTE-->
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="input-group">

      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
      <select class="form-control selectClientes" name="seleccionarCliente" id="seleccionarCliente">
        <option value="">Seleccione Cliente</option>
        <?php

        $item = null;
        $valor = null;
        $clientes = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);

        foreach ($clientes as $key => $value) {
          echo '<option value="' . $value["id"] . '">' . $value["establecimiento"] . ' - Municipalidad de ' . $value["municipio"] . ' - Partido de ' . $value["partido"] . '</option>';
        }

        ?>


      </select>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.selectClientes').select2();
        });
      </script>
      <span class="input-group-prepend">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarCliente">
          Agregar Cliente
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-3 form-group">
    <div class="icheck-success ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="nuevoDmc">
      <label class="ml-5 text-danger" for="nuevoDmc">Es un menu tipo DMC?
      </label>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ENTRADA PARA AGREGAR INGREDIENTES-->
<div class="form-group row nuevoIngrediente">


</div>
<!-- BOTON AGREGAR INGREDIENTE AL MENU -->
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnAgregarIngrediente">Agregar Ingrediente</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**viandas.js** -> Este **JS**, lo que hace es, a medida que el usuario le dá click al botón **«Agregar Ingrediente»**, dibuja en el **HTML** una fila que tiene un **Select** con sus **Options** para cargar un nuevo ingrediente a la receta:

```js
$(".btnAgregarIngrediente").click(function () {
  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("traerIngredientes", "ok");

  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/ingredientes.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (respuesta) {
      $(".nuevoIngrediente").append(
        '<div class="col-6">' +
        ' <div class="input-group">' +
        '  <span class="input-group-text"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" idIngrediente><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></span>' +
        '  <select class="form-control nuevoNombreIngrediente selectIngredientes" style="min-height:50px" idIngrediente name="nuevoNombreIngrediente" required>' +
        '  <option value="">Seleccione el ingrediente</option>' +
        '  </select>' +
        ' </div>' +
        '</div>' +

        '<div class="col-3">' +
        ' <input type="number" class="form-control" name="nuevaCantidadIngrediente" id="nuevaCantidadIngrediente" min="1" placeholder="0" required>' +
        ' <span class="small text-muted">&nbsp; Ingrese cantidad</span>' +
        '</div>' +

        '<div class="col-3">' +

        '<div class="input-group">' +
        ' <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt"></i></span>' +
        ' <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precioIngrediente" name="precioIngrediente" value="" readonly>' +
        ' </div><span class="small text-muted">Costo</span>' +
        '</div>'
      );

      // AGREGAR LOS INGREDIENTES AL SELECT

      respuesta.forEach(funcionForEach);

      function funcionForEach(item, index) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.selectIngredientes').select2();
        });

        $(".nuevoNombreIngrediente").append(
          '<option idIngrediente="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.nombre + '">' + item.nombre + '</option>'
        );
      }
    }
  });
});
```

> **EL PROBLEMA**: Cuando yo agrego una cierta cantidad de ingredientes, la fila de arriba para seleccionar clientes hace un salto de línea, dejando el botón **«Agregar Cliente»** abajo de la misma. Esto no debería pasar y no entiendo por qué ocurre. Adjunto dos (02) imágenes, de **antes** y **después** (en este caso la probé con la resolución de un monitor cuadrado, y apenas agregó un ingrediente, ya que se ve el problema. En resoluciones más altas me deja agregar hasta 6 elementos, recién allí se ve el problema).

**Antes:**
[image: Antes:]

**Después:**
[image: Después]

Comment: Comentario 1: Me pasa algo mucho mas extraño aun. Probe llevarme el script de ``select2`` arriba del DIV, y funciona mientras tenga el debugger abierto jaja, cuando lo cierro y cargo otro elemento, el boton baja. Que clase de brujeria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser que el mecanismo de `div` este provocando el problema que describes, hasta donde sé, una etiqueta `div` agrega un salto de linea al final, al contrario de la etiqueta `span`. El código donde esta tu botón parece estar encerrado en un `span` y luego en un `div`. Puede que por ahí puedas comenzar a depurar.

Una sugerencia sería encerrar los elementos del formulario en una tabla (select y button), para estructurarlos de tal forma que no se muevan.

Saludos

Comment: Probé cambiarle los valores con CSS a la propiedad display del div (inline y block) y no se vio ningún cambio (es decir, el problema se presenta de todas formas). El tema es que estoy usando el pluguin ``Select2``, que lo unico que hace (o para lo que lo uso ) es para tener un imput de busquea en el select de html. Este plugin renderiza un monton de elementos html y son los que generan el problema. Lo solucioné dandole un estilo en linea al div aplicandole un width maximo de 80%. Gracias por la respuesta y el tiempo.